# My keywords are decreasing - what should I do?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, keywords

I have a pet related site and posted 8 articles 2 months ago. Last month when I checked Google Search Console (search analytics) all my targeted keywords (8) for those articles were visible and they were moving forward.

But when I was checking for this month, I saw all those main keywords (8) are gone for those 8 articles.

Note: All articles are fresh, and they were checked for plagiarism, grammar, and that the word-count exceeded 750 words.

I just have a feeling that doing some quality backlinks will get those keywords back again, but I'm not sure about it. What should else should I do to help with this?

Comment: Search is not about keywords. It is about matching search intent. All this keyword SEO stuff is crap. The plain truth of the matter is your content, if well written and captive, will find the audience it should which often is different than what you imagined and tried to force upon a complex algorithm which is not only a secret, but also designed to reject too many suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you shouldn't worry if you have done nothing wrong in terms of SEO.

Some minor variation in ranking is completely normal.

**Backlink:** Yes, it will have you to get better ranking but needs to be done in right way.

**Recommendation:** The recommendation would be to focus more on content, include more images & videos if possible to make it intractive. Share that content on social media and let people know, you may get some natural linking.

Take step by step approach, there should be proper planning for backlink plan to do so.